# htaccess question: Remove 1(!) param from URL query

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

my URL looks like

page.html?L=0&a=1&b=2&c=6 OR
page.html?a=1&b=2&L=0&c=6 OR
page.html?a=1&b=2&c=6&L=0
I need to delete the L=0, where L can be either 0 or 1. But I need to keep all other params. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, another headache and I am finally there. I just post this here in case I

- missed something
- maybe this can help someone else in a similar situation

### .htaccess rule

```
# Rewrite Typo3 links with multilanguage Param "L"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(^L=[a-zA-Z0-9]+&?|^&L=[a-zA-Z0-9]+&|&L=[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(&?.*)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%3 [L,R=301]
```

### Explanation

The rule tries to cover all the following cases

- domain.com/login.html?p1=1&p2=2&L=abc&P3=3
- domain.com/login.html?p1=1&p2=2&L=def
- domain.com/login.html?&L=eh1
- domain.com/login.html?&L=asdfasd&p1=1&p2=2
- domain.com/login.html?L=0
- domain.com/login.html?L=1&p1=1&p2=2&P3=3

As far as my knowledge goes, the regex works as follow:

1. **(.*)** checks if there is anything before the following L-param option
2. The second **( )**-pair group contains 3 alternatives/cases on how the L-param could be present in the query string
3. the third **(.*)** simply covers everthing that might follow the L-param

Therefor the replacement only needs `%{REQUEST_URI}?%1%3`. This will cut out the second **( )** group with the different L-param options.

### End result

The URL query string will be stripped of the L-param, but leave everything else.

Any comments? Feel free to vote if this is valuable for you, too.

Thanks to all who helped me find the correct solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&+)*)L=[01](&+(.*))?$
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%4 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: "page.html" could be anything... Can I just put (.*)? I have seen this in many examples as ultimate wildcard...

Comment: you could use .* wildcard, but I suspect that when you say it can contain 'anything' that's not really what you mean. The more specific you can be the better. [a-zA-Z0-9-]+ would be fairly common, or possibly [^./]+

Comment: Hm... I am a little bit converned to use that code as I don't understand it completly. Would you mind to explain a little bit, so I can learn as well something?

Comment: @Czar: `(([^&]*&+)*)` will match any pairs of key and value in front of a key/value pair of `L=0` or `L=1` (since `L=[01]`). `(&+(.*))?` will match anything starting with at least one `&` after it. This is to get only the whole `L` values and not just values stat just start with `0` or `1`. So if the pattern in `RewriteRule` matches the current URI path without its contextual prefix and the pattern in `RewriteCond` matches the URI query, `%1` (match of first group in `RewriteCond`) contains everything before and `%3` (match of third group in `RewriteCond`) everything after the `L` parameter.

Comment: Hm... ok. 2 things:

1. I justed check, the "L" param can be pretty much anything, from numbers to chars to any arbitrary combination.

2. The Code says %1%4. Shoudln't this be %1%3 according to your explanation?

Comment: I put together all your tips and checked in gskinner.com/RegExr the expression. ^(([^&]*&+)*)L=[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(&+(.*))?$ with replacement $1$4 worked well, but only if the "L" param was NOT at the end of the URL. In that case a "&" was left at the end. Any way to solve this?

Comment: @Czar: No, `%1%4` is correct as it does not contain any leading `&`.

Comment: Ok, but what about the L Param not beeing at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I played around a lot on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/.

I simply can't find a regex that works on all these cases:

domain.com/login.html?p1=1&p2=2&L=0&P3=3
domain.com/login.html?p1=1&p2=2&L=1&P3=3
domain.com/login.html?p1=1&p2=2&L=0
domain.com/login.html?&L=0
domain.com/login.html?L=0
domain.com/login.html?L=0&p1=1&p2=2&P3=3

Last best guess was (.*)(L=[a-zA-Z0-9]&?)(&?)(.*) >>> $1$3$4

This resulted in

domain.com/login.html?p1=1&p2=2&P3=3
domain.com/login.html?p1=1&p2=2&P3=3
domain.com/login.html?p1=1&p2=2&
domain.com/login.html?&
domain.com/login.html?
domain.com/login.html?p1=1&p2=2&P3=3

What I try is:
- Cut out the L param if it is in the middle
- Cut off the L param if it is at the end of a loner param string
- Cut off the L param AND "?" if it is the only param

Can you provide some more hints?